Sort array with some negative indexes
I'm discovering Lua (context: factorio scripting) and I'm quite puzzled by the loose typing.
I'm trying to make a dictionary (int,structure) with an integer (and possibly negative key). And then sort it by that key.
local dic = {}
dic[1] = {t="foo"}
dic[25] = {t="bar"}
dic[-30] = {t="negative"}

table.sort(dic) -- oddly, that changes nothing

print(serpent.block(dic))
-- using ipairs() would make no sense for this structure
for k,v in pairs(dic) do
  print(serpent.line(k) .. " --> " .. serpent.line(v))
end

-- some processing that expects the array/dic/structure/thingy sorted by index

and that outputs
    {
      {
        t = "foo"
      },
      [-30] = {
        t = "negative"
      },
      [25] = {
        t = "bar"
      }
    }

-- sort didn't work
1 --> {t = "foo"}
25 --> {t = "bar"}
-30 --> {t = "negative"}

So, what am I doing wrong ?
Edit: thanks to answers, I now understand that ipairs() was not the right iterator for this data type. Removesd it from code for clarity

Given your input data, what output do you expect to get?

@Matt : I would expect the data sorted by index, in whatever form the language can provide. Solution found, see self-answer

(answer by OP)
After some hacking around, I managed to change my data structure to something that looks overkill, but at least it works
Don't take that as an optimal solution...
Instead of this (which does not sort, see answers)
local dic = {}
dic[1] = {t="foo"}
dic[25] = {t="bar"}
dic[-30] = {t="negative"}
-- try to sort that

... which gives an unsorted and unsortable
{
  {
    t = "foo"
  },
  [-30] = {
    t = "negative"
  },
  [25] = {
    t = "bar"
  }
}

I finally used
local dic = {}
table.insert(dic,  
  {key=1, value={t="foo", ...}}  
)
table.insert(dic,  
  {key=25, value={t="bar", ...}}  
)
table.insert(dic,  
  {key=-30, value={t="negative", ...}}  
)

-- sort with an explicit function
table.sort(thresholds, 
  function(kv1,kv2) 
    return kv1.k < kv2.k end
)

for _,kv in pairs(dic) do
  -- processing
end

which gives a more complex, and sortable
{
  {
    key=1,
    value= { t = "foo", ...}
  },
  ...
}


table.sort(dic, return kv1.key < kv2.key

Lua table keys are not stored in any particular order. When you iterate a table with pairs, you see the contents in whatever order the interpreter finds convenient.
Sequences are implemented by using consecutive integer keys starting at 1 and going up. Your dic table has a [1] key but no [2], so table.sort and ipairs basically just see it as a 1-element sequence. Sorting works by changing which keys point to which elements.
You have basically 2 choices:

Keep it like it is, so you can refer to things by their current key.

Add your current keys to their corresponding tables, so you can use normal sequence keys and keep the tables in a specific order.


You could also try to get the best of both worlds, but the solution would be complicated and would depend on what your priorities are.

As @luther has said, Lua tables are not sorted.
However, they can be iterated in a required order, including by key ascending.
To do so, you need to reload the pairs() function for the dictionary, by defining __pairs metamethod.
--[[
    This function will convert the simple table tbl
    into a table that pairs() will iterate
    in the order of its keys ascending.
    The table will preserve its qualities after adding
    or removing items.
--]]
local function sorted_by_key (tbl)
    return setmetatable (tbl, {
        __pairs = function (t)
            local keys = {}
            --[[
                Get the keys of t and sort them.
                We cannot use for key, _ in pairs (t), as it is reloaded
                and we would start an infinite recursion.
            --]]
            key, _ = next (t)
            while key do
                keys [#keys + 1] = key
                key, _ = next (t, key)              
            end
            table.sort (keys)

            local key = 0 -- this counter will be incremented by pairs.
            return function ()
                key = key + 1
                return keys [key], t [keys [key]]
            end
        end
    })
end

print 'Initial dic:'
local dic = sorted_by_key {
    [1] = 'foo',
    [25] = 'bar',
    [-30] = 'negative',
    [100] = 'very positive',
    [-100] = 'very negative'
}

for key, value in pairs (dic) do
    print (key, value)
end

print 'With an added item at key 50:'
dic [50] = 'moderately positive'
for key, value in pairs (dic) do
    print (key, value)
end

print 'With a removed item at key 25:'
dic [25] = nil
for key, value in pairs (dic) do
    print (key, value)
end

